# Are there scenarios where the used heap memory reduces without GC i.e. when there is no GC event?

Tags: java, android, garbage-collection

I see in my Android app, a decrease in used memory even when GC has not occured. I don't see GC in my logs for that time period. How else is the memory released, if not by GC? Is it by objects that specifically deallocate memory when exiting?

Comment: How *exactly* are you determining that there is "a decrease in used memory even when GC has not occured"?

Comment: @CommonsWare, by calling (Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory() - Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory()) immediately before and after a certain a bunch of codes.